when I try to run Python 3.13, it immediately gives an "ImportError"
I type command "python3.13" (on MacOS/terminal/csh) and get response:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/prowat/.pythonstartup", line 6, in <module>
    from math import pi, coth, cos, tanh, cosh, log, exp, pow, sqrt, fabs, expm1
ImportError: cannot import name 'coth' from 'math' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/lib-dyn
>>> 

I don't know what that .pythonstartup file is or how it got there.
How can this be fixed?
I tried to run the latest Python, Python3.13, and immediately got the response described above.

You probably have a PYTHONSTARTUP var set.  Unset it.

Just to note, whoever did create this file may have confused the built-in math module with the 3rd-party mpmath module, which does provide a coth function.

Get this file out of the way regardless- shadowing builtin pow with math.pow has the potential to cause unpleasant and subtle behavior changes in the interactive interpreter vs script/modules.

This doesn't seem specific to 3.13 since math.coth doesn't exist on any version AFAICT.

Files starting with . in the filename are hidden, but you can still edit them.  From the command line ls -a will show them all.

I don't know where your .pythonstartup file came from either, but I I'm sure that it was not from installing Python, not least because the file is wrong.  Presumably, it is named in environment variable PYTHONSTARTUP, which also would not have been set by installing Python.  When Python is launched in interactive mode, as you seem to be doing, any file named by that variable is loaded and run automatically, before the prompt is presented.
Not knowing where that .pythonstartup file came from or why it is there, I would be hesitant to remove it.  Having such an error in it does not inspire trust, however, so I would recommend updating your shell environment configuration so that it does not set the PYTHONSTARTUP variable.  Or so that it unsets that variable if it is being set via system-wide configuration.  Details of how to do that depend in part on which shell you are using.  Since you mention csh in the question, you're probably looking for something in your .login or .cshrc file.

Not quite before anything else, site hooks will run first.

I guess it depends on how you take "anything else", @wim.  Lest that ambiguity cause any genuine confusion, I have modified the text in a manner I hope you find satisfactory.
